# vb.net buttons won't click after editing them

Tags: vb.net

I made a nice program while learning and everything was going good until I did something, but I forgot what I did.  Now the buttons won't click but they all have the functions.

I know it's something in the properties but I forgot what it was.

vb.net express 2013

Comment: If they wont click, make sure they have the handles clause... If the handles clause is missing the event wont happen. Also without code we cant really help as to what would be happening...

Comment: Create a new button, make sure it works, and then compare the properties of the button that works to one that doesn't.

Comment: Does the button appear to depress?

Answer (score 0):

Without code provided, we can't really help that much. But what you can do is create another button, then copy whatever the code of your old button was, and paste it to your new button created.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio when you cut and paste any `Control` instead of simply drag it in a new position it will lost every event handler already added.

In your case simply add `Handles` clause to your `YourButtonName_Click` sub:

```
Private Sub YourButtonName_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles YourButtonName.Click
```